# Training registration in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, joomla

I would like to do a site in PHP/MySQL using either Drupal/Joomla/Wordpress that allows me to have class list with description/date and students can sign up to pay for it. I prefer Wordpress if there is some package already. The idea is to have students to pay via Paypal. For backend, Admin should be able to manage class, check students status.

The reason I want to do this is because I have a small company and I want to do special workshop once in awhile.

Any recommendation on something already built close to this?

Comment: If you're looking for something pre-built, try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with WordPress and one of several event registration plugins.  These two plugins integrate with paypal

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-events-registration/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-registration/

Check out this blog article that mentions more plugins for event registration

http://www.moongoosedesigns.com/event-and-event-management-registration-plugins-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

http://eventespresso.com/ is the evolution of advanced events registration. It's good, and does exactly what you need. I use it for just that on firstlineeducation.com